# websocket getting weird characters

Tags: python, websocket

Hi I've been testing out websockets and so far I got it connected and all. But when I starting send and data to the server I getting a bunch of weird characters.

(got these codes from searching)

Here's the server:

```
import socket
import re
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha1

websocket_answer = (
    'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols',
    'Upgrade: websocket',
    'Connection: Upgrade',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {key}\r\n\r\n',
)

GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8999))
s.listen(1)

client, address = s.accept()
text = client.recv(1024)
print "RECV----------------------------------"
print text

key = (re.search('Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s+(.*?)[\n\r]+', text)
    .groups()[0]
    .strip())

response_key = b64encode(sha1(key + GUID).digest())
response = '\r\n'.join(websocket_answer).format(key=response_key)

print "SEND----------------------------------"
print response
client.send(response)

while 1:
    try :
        print "SEND----------------------------------"
        client.sendall('hello from server')
        print "RECV----------------------------------"
        print client.recv(1024)
    except :
        print "except"
        break
```

Here's the client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>WebSocket Echo Client</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script>
    "use strict";
    // Initialize everything when the window finishes loading
    window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
      var status = document.getElementById("status");
      var url = document.getElementById("url");
      var open = document.getElementById("open");
      var close = document.getElementById("close");
      var send = document.getElementById("send");
      var text = document.getElementById("text");
      var message = document.getElementById("message");
      var socket;

      status.textContent = "Not Connected";
      url.value = "ws://localhost:8999";
      close.disabled = true;
      send.disabled = true;

      // Create a new connection when the Connect button is clicked
      open.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        open.disabled = true;
        socket = new WebSocket(url.value, "echo-protocol");

        socket.addEventListener("open", function(event) {
          close.disabled = false;
          send.disabled = false;
          status.textContent = "Connected";
        });

        // Display messages received from the server
        socket.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
          message.textContent = "Server Says: " + event.data;
        });

        // Display any errors that occur
        socket.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
          message.textContent = "Error: " + event;
        });

        socket.addEventListener("close", function(event) {
          open.disabled = false;
          status.textContent = "Not Connected";
        });
      });

      // Close the connection when the Disconnect button is clicked
      close.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        close.disabled = true;
        send.disabled = true;
        message.textContent = "";
        socket.close();
      });

      // Send text to the server when the Send button is clicked
      send.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        socket.send(text.value);
        text.value = "";
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  Status: <span id="status"></span><br />
  URL: <input id="url" /><br />
  <input id="open" type="button" value="Connect" />&nbsp;
  <input id="close" type="button" value="Disconnect" /><br />
  <input id="send" type="button" value="Send" />&nbsp;
  <input id="text" /><br />
  <span id="message"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is what Im getting once I hit the connect button:

```
RECV----------------------------------
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:8999
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: echo-protocol
Sec-WebSocket-Key: v6Fu1rJURofc7iIPbeaw0Q==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
Cookie: BG_PREFS=searches_includeapocrypha@no&fontsize@medium&language@en&default_version_display@all&default_version@SND&default_
version_overrides@no&quicksearch_search@&pslookup_language1@en&pslookup_language2@&pslookup_language3@&pslookup_language4@&pslooku
p_language5@&pslookup_showmoresearches@closed&pslookup_showversions@open&pslookup_showmoreversions@closed&pslookup_showoptions@ope
n&pslookup_showfootnotes@yes&pslookup_showxrefs@no&pslookup_showwoj@no&pslookup_showversenums@yes&pslookup_showheadings@yes&pslook
up_showindent@no&pslookup_multilayout@columns&pslookup_multisort@passage&pslookup_embed-versenum@true&pslookup_embed-xref@false&ps
lookup_embed-footnote@false&pslookup_embed-heading@false&keysearch_search@&keysearch_language1@en&keysearch_language@en&
SEND----------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: echo-protocol
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: qVkmFtRs1w8OUwZSe5nMpTWNxbI=


SEND----------------------------------
RECV----------------------------------
keysearch_bookset@&keysearch_spanbegin@1&keysearch_spanend@73&keysearch_limit@none&keysearch_startnumber@1&keysearch_searchtype@al
l&keysearch_showversions@open&keysearch_showmoreversions@closed&keysearch_showoptions@open&keysearch_displayas@long&keysearch_resu
ltspp@25&keysearch_sort@bookorder&keysearch_wholewordsonly@no&commentary_source@1&topindex_source@1&topindex_search@&topindex_sear
ch_type@any&topindex_resultspp@25&audio_source@3&audio_book@&audio_chapter@&dict_source@1&dict_search@&dict_search_type@any&pslook
up_search@>>>>&pslookup_version@NIV>>>>&undefined&keysearch_version@31>>>>; CoreID6=83844698672113373932637&ci=90320803; __atuvc=2
|20
```

Handshake seems fine, it connected.
And then when I send the text "test" from the client I get this.

```
üäQk╩¼%♫╣╪
```

Does this have anything to do with character encoding?
I am unable to get the "test" string I sent to the server.
And I also didn't get anything on the client side.

Note:
I tested the client on Chrome 19.

Comment: What version of python is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to RFC the client sends no text data, but [binary frames](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5).

Comment: Sorry for the noob comment. But how do you read/handle binary frames?

Comment: See for example this implementation: https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado/blob/master/sockjs/tornado/websocket.py#L490

Comment: Just found a simpler implementation [link](http://bogboa.blogspot.com/2012/02/unpacking-websocket-frame.html)

Thanks for the help dionys

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets is a framed protocol. It has similar latency to raw sockets, but the data is not sent raw over the wire:

- **Header**: There is a two byte header at the beginning of the frame. This can also be a 4 byte or 10 byte header if the payload is longer than 125 bytes or 65535 bytes respectively.
- **Binary or Text**: The header also indicates whether the data is binary or text. In your case the data is text. To send binary data you must send an ArrayBuffer or Blob from the Javascript. If you send a string then the data will be text. If the server sends a binary frame then the onmessage event will receive either a blob or arraybuffer depending on the setting of the WebSocket.binaryType field.
- **Masking**: All data from client (browser) to server must be masked. This is to address a theoretical concern in misbehaving caching intermediaries. Data from server to client must not be masked. The header has a bit that indicates whether the payload is masked. If it is masked then the first four bytes after the header are the mask. This is applied as a running XOR to the payload data in order to unmask it.

In your example, you sent a text string "test". The server received 10 bytes of data: 2 byte header, 4 byte mask, 4 bytes of masked payload.

See [section 5.2 of the IETF 6455 WebSocket protocol specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2) for a diagram of how the framing works and the bit-level breakdown of fields in the header.

Comment: Is there any simple way of handling these? I found this. [link](http://popdevelop.com/2010/03/a-minimal-python-websocket-server/)

Comment: That's an example of processing the vary old version of the protocol that had very different framing. Here is a python example of decoding the IETF 6455 (HyBi) version of the protocol: https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/blob/master/websocket.py#L301 It uses the python numpy module but you don't have to. The code should at least give you an idea of how to process the framing.